# Broken “Edit Page” Link on Wordpress Admin Bar

Tags: wordpress, admin, multisite

(Having to re-post this issue as the url was not showing correctly in the original post.)

I have a multisite Wordpress installation into which I had imported several sites. All is working fine except for the "Edit Page" link in the Admin Bar. It is using the html "&" instead of "&" in the url:

(update - I am having to include the url as an image, since stackoverlow keeps automatically converting the html '&" to "&".) [See an image of the url here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmtzq.png)

In the image, note the issue after "post=32"

I have created several multisite installations successfully and have never seen this. I have tried disabling all plugins to no avail and have spent hours scouring google for a similar issue but haven't found it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the database to see if there's an extra ampersand in the title or slug of the posts.

Comment: I have checked the urls in the database and they seem fine. Also, if you look at the structure of Edit Page link, it is generated by Wordpress code. The only component of link relevant to the page is the page ID.  Is it possible that Apache is using the wrong character set for Wordpress. I believe it is using UTF-8